# Azure Wordpress site - URLs not showing on move from root to subdirectory

Tags: php

Moved the site from the Root to a Sub-directory by following these instructions http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

- Changed the Wordpress site URL and Site URL (the same in this case)
- Created sub-directory
- Edited the index.php
- Copied the all files to the sub-directory (except web.config)
- Moved the "web.config" file to the sub-directory
- Checked the permalinks

I am able to login into wp-admin, but not of the pages are showing content viewed - just blank page.

This is first time using Azure - please excuse my ignorance.

shelleyjane

Answer (score 1):

According the post you provided, if you are following the section **Moving a Root install to its own directory**, it seems will make the wordpress dashboard panel via visiting url like `"http://example.com/<sub-folder>/..."` and wordpress frontend site via `"http://example.com"`.

If this is your requirement, it seems there are some different steps with my test and which works fine on my side. You can try my settings:

- Changed the **Wordpress site URL** to `"http://<web_app_name>.azurewebsites.net/<sub-folder-name>"`
- Do not change the **Site address (URL)** (keep to`"http://<web_app_name>.azurewebsites.net"`)
- **Move** your WordPress core files to the sub-folder, except `web.config`.
- create `index.php` in root directory (outside sub-folder), with contain:

  `define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
  require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );`
- Check the permalinks

Here is the final structure of my Azure Web App:

[image]

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick response. I completed the move successfully to the sub-directory. I think because I had 'copied' the core files to the sub-directory instead of 'move' them was my mistake. I did have to copy the index.php to the root and then change the details, rather than create a new index.php. Thanks again.